# How does one link with the SoftFloat library?

Tags: c

I am designing hardware to do floating point arithmetic in compliance with the IEEE-754 standard. SoftFloat is a library (written by John Hauser - UC Berkeley) which is a reference model (in C++) of IEEE-754 floating point behavior. It implements functions to do all the floating point computations specified by the standard. I want to use SoftFloat to generate test cases for my hardware implementation. The link for the author's page is http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/SoftFloat.html.

I downloaded the zip file from the link on that page (http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/SoftFloat-3e.zip), unzipped it, and used to provided Makefile to build it. I am running under bash on Windows10. At the end of the build process, I end up with an archive "softfloat.a".

One of the functions which SoftFloat implements is fused floating-point multiply-add. Per the documentation, this can be invoked by calling the function f32_mulAdd, and a template for it is in the provided header file softfloat.h.

In my main code (sf.cc), I include that header, define arguments to that function using types defined in the same header, and build the code with:

```
gcc -o sf -I. sf.cc softfloat.a
```

This gives the following error:

```
/tmp/ccALxpC8.o: In function `main':
sf.cc:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `f32_mulAdd(float32_t, float32_t, float32_t)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

f32_mulAdd IS defined in softfloat.h (I checked), and the archive file softfloat.a DOES contain f32_mulAdd.o (checked with ar -t softfloat.a) and f32_mulAdd.c in the SoftFloat source code DOES define the function (as "float32_t f32_mulAdd( float32_t a, float32_t b, float32_t c)") and my call to that function is consistent with the definition, so I don't understand why I get this message. If anyone has used SoftFloat please chime in.

The source code in which I call the SoftFloat function f32_mulAdd is as follows (I want to get this to compile/link cleanly first, then I will add statements to initialize the variables multiplier, multiplicand and addend to specific values):

```
#include "platform.h"
#include "internals.h"
#include "softfloat.h"
#include "softfloat_types.h"

int float_rounding_mode = 0;

int main()
{
    uint8_t rounding_mode;
    uint8_t exceptions;

    uint32_t multiplier, multiplicand, addend, result;
    float32_t f_multiplier, f_multiplicand, f_addend, f_result;

    f_multiplier.v = multiplier;
    f_multiplicand.v = multiplicand;
    f_addend.v = addend;

    softfloat_roundingMode = rounding_mode;
    softfloat_exceptionFlags = 0;
    softfloat_detectTininess = softfloat_tininess_beforeRounding;

    f_result = f32_mulAdd(f_multiplier, f_multiplicand, f_addend);

    result = f_result.v;    
    exceptions = softfloat_exceptionFlags & 0x1f;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The key is to change the header file inclusion to:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "softfloat.h"
}
```

Also, softfloat.h was the only header file required.

Answer (score -4):

There is no need to use a softfloat library.

The GCC compiler already have a floating point implementation.

For-eg - You can just do a A + B on float types and you should get the result. 
You can also control the rounding mode using `std::fesetround()` and get the exceptions by using.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. The purpose of SoftFloat is not to use floating point. It’s to use it on hardware or compilers that don’t support the needed floating point sizes.